# HERE Maps specific domain feature not working

Tags: here-api

When I set the domain in the dashboard to xxxxxx.com, where xxxxx is my domain, I am still unable to make API calls from the domain given.

The error I get when I attempt to make an API call is:

"Unauthorized. The request is not from an authorized source."

There is no issue with the code itself as it was working before I had set a specific domain. I've also ensured that the domain typed into the dashboard is correct.

Any help would be appreciated, will provide more information, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a bit of time for the changes to take effect. Please wait a little while, then try again. If it still doesn't work, please report back.

Alternatively please note that you also need to add any subdomains you may be using. For example, if you add "here.com", you would also have to add "www.here.com" and "developer.here.com" if you wanted API calls to be accepted from these subdomains.

Comment: I've waited overnight (approx 8 hours). Is that not enough?

Last night it was working without having the domain set (I was able to hit the API from any website). I then added my domain and after 8 hours I am unable to hit the API from anywhere.

Comment: The API works when I don't have a specific domain set. When I set it, I am unable to access the API from anywhere, including the site with the domain I tried to set.

Comment: I have extended my answer with another possible solution. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I don't have any subdomains for my site. It's just xxxxxx.com which i've added to the dashboard. I also tried to add to the dashboard the specific pages, for example xxxxxx.com/example but that didn't work either.

Comment: I also added my server IP to the dashboard and tried to make a curl request directly from the server and that didn't work either. This seems to be some permission not being set properly when I make my tokens authorized. 

I ensured I waited enough time so that's not the issue.

Comment: Please use the "contact us" form on the developer portal so we can look into your account and see what the issue is.

Comment: I have used the "contact us" form. I am directed to a sales team representative who doesn't help me. I've used it twice, both times it was the same representative, and both times he told me to go to stack overflow.

Comment: Please refer directly to this thread. I have let the team know about your case.

Comment: I appreciate you letting them know. I'll be looking forward for help from them. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rony. Please contact us through: selfservesupport@here.com, provide your App ID and I will check. Thanks!