# Trusted domains not working for HERE Maps App

Tags: here-api

In the HERE platform, I added an App under Apps in the Access Manager. I then generated an API key for this app. This API key works when using it on our webapp.

However, when I add a "Trusted domain" and "Enable trusted domains", the key no longer works. I added all variations of our domain:

- sub.domain.com
- https://sub.domain.com
- domain.com

I have waited multiple hours between different attempts and it still doesn't work. When I disable trusted domains, it works again...

The following question seems related but there is no solution: [HERE Maps specific domain feature not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468750/here-maps-specific-domain-feature-not-working)

Is this feature not working properly, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to pass the "Referer" + Your trusted domains in the header.
Example: If you have your IPV4 address in the trusted domain and use some tools like postman to test it. Then add Referer and the IP in the headers. It should work. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, this is not solving my issues. The calls to the HERE API are only done from a deployed application on https://sub.domain.com - so not via Postman.
When the calls are made, the referer is automatically set by the browser: `Referer: https://sub.domain.com/`
As I said, all combinations that I could think of are added to the list of trusted domains. However, including the '/' at the end is not allowed. So I've added:
- sub.example.com
- http://sub.example.com
- https://sub.example.com
- example.com
- http://example.com
- https://example.com